# What mission and i missing?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

Okay guys. So I've completely finished all the main missions of unity. I've found

- all the helix rifts
- heists coop missions
- social club missions
- Paris stories
- murder mysteries
- nostradamus enigmas
- café theatre missions.

But there is one greyed out mission column that I can't access? Can anyone tell me what it is? I'd add a photo but the site won't let me.

Comment: you can use sites like [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/) to upload images and use the link there though i question that you can't upload an image as i don't belive there is a [new user restriction](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) on adding an image

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're missing the Companion Missions, which are generated by completing Nomand Brotherhood missions in the [Unity companion app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.assassin.unity.companion) (also [on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/assassins-creed-unity-companion/id896612702?mt=8)):

[image: progression companion mission bar]

They're just simple assassination missions, but the in-app component can take a while, making getting them a bit tedious.